# R conditional variable

Tags: r

I want to calculate a new variable (mean.BC) conditional of x= BC5,BC6,BC7 for each 'SITE'. In other words take mean(19,70,84) and past the result in all rows that have site "a" then do the same on all the rows with site "b, c, etc..." except that the values of "y" for BC5,BC6,BC7 
would change at each site.

this might not be the best way of doing it, I did tried spreading the data with tidyr::spread() using "x" as key but id didn't
made any more sense to me.

```r
x <- c("A1", "B2", "C3", "D4", "BC5", "BC6", "BC7")
y <- c(34, 45, 11, 10, 19, 70, 84, 12, 45, 55, 67, 89, 23, 1)
site <- c(rep("a", 7), rep("b", 7))

test.data <- data.frame(site, x, y)

# site x  y   meanBC
# 1    a        A1 34   
# 2    a        B2 45
# 3    a        C3 11
# 4    a        D4 10
# 5    a       BC5 19
# 6    a       BC6 70

test.data %>% as.tibble() %>% 
  group_by(site) %>% 
  mutate(meanBC= if_else(test.data$x==c("BC5","BC6","BC7"), mean(y), 999))
#> Error in test.data %>% as.tibble() %>% group_by(site) %>% mutate(meanBC = if_else(test.data$x == : could not find function "%>%"
```

the desired result should look something like this:

```
site rep.x..2.  y   meanBC
# 1    a        A1 34   57.6
# 2    a        B2 45   57.6
# 3    a        C3 11   57.6
# 4    a        D4 10   57.6
# 5    a       BC5 19   57.6
# 6    a       BC6 70   57.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, we could `group_by` `site` and calculate `mean` of `y` whose corresponding `x` is one of `c("BC5", "BC6","BC7")`.

```
library(dplyr)
test.data %>%
   group_by(site) %>%
   mutate(mean.BC = mean(y[x %in% c("BC5", "BC6","BC7")]))

#  site   x       y mean.BC
# <fct>  <fct> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 a     A1       34    57.7
# 2 a     B2       45    57.7
# 3 a     C3       11    57.7
# 4 a     D4       10    57.7
# 5 a     BC5      19    57.7
# 6 a     BC6      70    57.7
# 7 a     BC7      84    57.7
# 8 b     A1       12    37.7
# 9 b     B2       45    37.7
#10 b     C3       55    37.7
#11 b     D4       67    37.7
#12 b     BC5      89    37.7
#13 b     BC6      23    37.7
#14 b     BC7       1    37.7
```

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test.data)[, mean.BC := mean(y[x %in% c("BC5", "BC6","BC7")]), by = site]
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R` we can do

```
test.data$mean.BC <- with(test.data, ave(y * NA^!(x %in%  c("BC5", "BC6","BC7")), 
    site, FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
test.data$mean.BC
#[1] 57.66667 57.66667 57.66667 57.66667 57.66667 57.66667 57.66667 
#[8] 37.66667 37.66667 37.66667 37.66667 37.66667 37.66667 37.66667
```

Comment: I understand almos everything in the piece of code you posted, except the  ...y*NA^!...    @akrun could you tell me what is that doing?

Comment: @CarLinneo  It is to create `NA` with a logical expression. e.g. `NA^(c(TRUE, FALSE))` returns `NA` for TRUE and 1 for FALSE.  When you do negate (`!`), all 0 values change to `TRUE` and others FALSE.   So, we get `NA` for the 0 and others 1 which when multiplied with the `sum` returns the expected